# Arbitrary content in top-nav dropdown in Foundation 5?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to put arbitrary content inside a dropdown in the nav bar for Zurb Foundation 5. Essentially, all I want is a login button that opens a login form dropdown. It seems that Foundation only supports `<ul>` lists for dropdowns in the top bar, even though dropdowns outside of the nav bar let you use any content with a `f-dropdown content` class.

This is pretty simple to accomplish with Bootstrap, but I was under the impression that Foundation is designed to be more customizable. Surely this is possible? Another example use case is the StackExchange logo dropdown - it contains various scrollable content, including a search form. How can something like that be built in Foundation?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to do in Foundation aswell, unless I misunderstood what you want - couldn't you just simply do something like this?

```
<li class="has-drodown">
   <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
   <ul class="dropdown">add your login form here..</ul>
</li>
```

There's alot of examples in the docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

If you don't want the dropdown to show on hover, you can add `is_hover: false` to `data-options` - like so:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false">
```

Comment: Did you try this? The form will not display correctly, even when put inside a dropdown `<li>`. Notice how the docs only show simple dropdown lists with textual `<a>` elements. It is possible to use a content dropdown button in the topbar, which displays fine on large screens but does not work correctly in the collapsed small screen topbar.

Comment: The official response from the Foundation team is essentially "The topbar is not designed to do this." - https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3967 Although it seems someone is now assigned to the issue, maybe they will fix this?

Comment: Should just be a matter of adding some css overrides, I think I used the topbar for this for a recent project in Foundation5 - but I might remember wrong. Anyways, I can have a look later and post the code if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/navigation.php#btopEx

> Arbitrary Content Dropdowns
>
> You can also have dropdowns with a specific size which can contain any kind of content, including rows and columns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is from the Foundation 3.2.5 docs, not the Foundation 5 docs.

Comment: I did find the dropdown content button, maybe that would be close enough? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

Comment: Unfortunately it does not display correctly in small-screen (collapsed) mode. See this issue on github: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3967